# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MembersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sorry for my bad english first.
I just installed ruby and rails few hours ago (you wouldn't believe it took me 3 days to install ruby,rvm,rails and etc, on this ubuntu 10.04 machine) and I am trying to implement basic Member scaffold. My version of rails is 3.0.0 and my ruby is 1.9.2.

When I `#rails generate scaffold Member email:string password:string` it created various files. I also did `#rake db:migrate` to implement database in mysql.
So within member controller, I saw that I have to go through 127.0.0.1:3000/members/ to get to the basic scaffold setup.

I just changed

```
def new
  @member = Member.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @member }
  end
end
```

above statements in member controller into

```
def register
  @member = Member.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @member }
  end
end
```

U see, I just changed the new into register, and now, when I try to get into 
127.0.0.1:3000/members/register 
The `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error shows up.
How can I resolve this problem?
I just want to make
127.0.0.1:3000/members/register 
to be a page where user can register..

btw, this RoR seems to be very complicated, and api documents seems to be too broad to be understood for beginners. I ordered a RoR book last week, so I will see how it goes...

Answer (score 5):

By using the scaffold generator members gets mapped as a resource. Look in the `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :members
```

When entities are mapped as resources they get a set of default routes. You can see all your mapped routes by doing  `rake routes`

```
members GET     /members(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>" members"}
members POST    /members(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=> "members"}
new_member GET  /members/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"members"}
edit_member GET /members/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"members"}
member GET      /members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members"}
member PUT      /members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"members"}
member DELETE   /members/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"members"}
```

When you rename the `new` action to `register` there no longer is a valid route for that mapping.

What you could do is to leave the action as `new` and just add the following route in your `routes.rb`

```
match 'members/register' => 'members#new'
```

This way you do not break other things in the scaffold. If you really want to rename the action to register I would suggest not using scaffolds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for nice answer. Now I get how rails 3 get done in mapping. :)

Comment: Hi again. If I want to set something like

Comment: edit_password_member GET    /members/:id/edit_password(.:format) {:action=>"edit_password", :controller=>"members"}

Where can I do so? in a 'routes' file??

Comment: Yes! in routes.rb. If you create a new question I will be happy to provide you with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'register' method to routes, like:-

map.connect '/members/register', :controller => 'members', :action => 'register'.

After adding the above to routes.rb restart the server.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: You mean just put -> map.connect '/members/register', :controller => 'members', :action => 'register' <- in a route.rb file? I did so, but I am getting a undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000000030c64a0> (NameError)

Comment: You need to put the above line in like ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map| map.connect'/members/register', :controller => 'members', :action => 'register' end

Comment: I'm not sure that's true for rails 3. The routing has changed quite considerably iirc.

Comment: To do that in Rails3 you have to do the following: match 'members/register' => 'members#register'

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem when creating a new html.erb.
Even my routes.rb  **match 'controller/action' => 'controller#action'**    were correct.
Later I found that the problem was that the **resources :controller** were above the match.

This is the correct order that worked for me:

> **match 'controller/action' => 'controller#action'
>  resources :controller**

Thanks to **pavlo** for asking this question, and to **maz** because his answer gave me the hint that the **resources** were involved in the error.